# For a compact abelian group, what can I conclude if range of a character is finite?

Tags: fourier-analysis, characters

Suppose $G$ is a compact abelian group, and suppose $<g^n>$ is dense in $G$ where $g$ is a particular element of $G$ and $<g^n>$ is the subgroup generated by $g$. Let $\chi$ be a character on $G$ such that $\{\chi(x):x\in G\}$ is finite.

Then, can I conclude that $\chi$ is trivial on $G$?

So what I realized is this: take a sequence $g^{n_k}$ converging to $1$, then $\chi(g^{n_k})\to1$ but as range of $\chi$ is finite, we have $\chi(g^N)=1$ for some $N$ implying $\chi(g)^N=1$ implying $\chi(g)$ is an $N$-th root of unity.

Then I also observe that for any $x$, if we take $g^{n_j}\to x$ then by analogous argument as above, there exists $J_x$ with $\chi(x)=\chi(g)^{J_x}$.

So all points in range ($\chi$) lie on the $N$ vertices of a regular $N$ gon constructed inscribed in the unit circle.

Comment: What do you mean by "$<g^n>$"?

Comment: It is the subgroup generated by $g$, a particular element of $G$.

Comment: Please see the edit @EricWofsey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all.  For a trivial counterexample, let $G$ be a finite cyclic group.

More generally, an element $g\in G$ which generates a dense subgroup is equivalent to a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\to G$ with dense image.  By Pontryagin duality, this is equivalent to an injective homomorphism $\hat{G}\to S^1$, where $\hat{G}$ is the character group of $G$.  Your question then becomes: is every subgroup of $S^1$ torsion-free?  The answer is obviously no.